# observer create multiple message with socket.io in angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

i am using of this code for receive MSG to socket in angular 2 but i have used in global application but it's created multiple time msgs.. on routeing another pages i created one chat-box component which opened global after open like Facebook chat-box.

```
  `get-messages() {
    let observable = new Observable(observer => {
      this.socket = io(this.url);
      this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);    
      });
      return () => {
        this.socket.disconnect();
      };  
    })     
    return observable;
   } `
```

Comment: any body can help for this multiple messages problem solve

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help or not. In angular 1.x I use

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(event) {
    // Code to un observe the socket here...
});
```

I am sure there is an equivalent in angular 2

Comment: How I will use this